# I can't open a downloaded file with an input stream in Android Studio

Tags: android, file, kotlin

I am successfully able to download a file, but when I try to open it, I get a file not found exception. I appear to be writing and accessing the same directory. I added the read and write permissions in the app's manifest file.

```
setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, "fileName.txt")
.....
myInputStream = assets.open(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/fileName.txt")
```

Comment: `AssetManager` is not working with files on the filesystem of the device, let alone downloaded ones. `assets.open()` is unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: What function would be what I want instead of AssetManager?

Comment: `FileInputStream(File(Environment.getExternalPublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)), "fileName.txt")`, most likely.